# Give Canvas toDataURL a .png extension for use with Key Lemon

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm trying to implement Key Lemon's face detection API into my application. In order to use it, I need to provide the API with several image URLs using one of the following image formats. JPEG, PNG, GIF or BMP.

What I want to know is, is it possible to use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` to generate am image URL with a `.png` extension at the end of it so that the Key Lemon API can recognize it as an actual image?

Here is piece of code that I'm using to take a picture of the user from their webcam and provide that image to Key Lemon's face detection API

Capture and draw image:

```
var video = document.querySelector('#videoElement');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
$scope.userImageURLs.push(dataURL);
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 210, 155);
```

Send image to API:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://klws.keylemon.com/api/face/?user=user_name&key=my_key&urls='+dataURL;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status  === 200) {
            responseToJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log('All OK: ', xmlhttp.readyState);
        }
        else {
            console.log('NOT OK:');
            console.log(xmlhttp.readyState, xmlhttp.status);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('POST', url);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does that service really accept images as `GET` parameters? Usually such data as images are sent by `POST` requests

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: i faced same issue, have you resolved yet?i need image url from the dataurl